# Ordering of nominal values for Class Attribute in weka

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, weka, svm

During the creating of my training set, I entered "true" and "false" in the same order as it was entered while creating the test set in WEKA. These nominal values are for the class attribute.

When I run a classifier, I somehow feel that the results look as if it is reversed in the test set.

My question is if the first line in the training set shows that the class value is "False", and if the trained model is used in the SVM classifier on a test set, does it mean if the returned classified class is 0, should I consider it as False?

Thanks
Abhishek S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the nominal attribute was defined in the same order in both data sets (training and test).
The output will be in the same order.

Nominal values are coded as "double".
So if you wrote: {false, true} => "false" = 0.0 and "true" = 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://waikato.github.io/weka-wiki/use_weka_in_your_java_code/#classifying-instances) is the excerpt from the weka documentation.

> The returned double value from  classifyInstance (or the index in the
>   array returned by distributionForInstance) is just the index for the
>   string values in the attribute. That is, if you want the string
>   representation for the class label returned above clsLabel, then you
>   can print it like this:

```
System.out.println(clsLabel + " -> " + unlabeled.classAttribute().value((int) clsLabel));
```

Comment: link is broken. I think it moved to [https://waikato.github.io/weka-wiki/use_weka_in_your_java_code/#classifying-instances](https://waikato.github.io/weka-wiki/use_weka_in_your_java_code/#classifying-instances)